# Is it possible to decode a session cookie

Tags: server, aws

I am working on AWS DeepRacer. I have obtained the session cookie and the DeepRacer token. I wanted to know if it is possible to use both of them to obtain the password to the DeepRacer.

I have the password already, I just wanted to show that it is possible to obtain it as well.

Comment: This is a question for Stack Overflow as it's not specifically related to Ubuntu ... or any version of Linux as far as I can tell. As for your question, the answer is "no". The session ID is not an encoded version of the password. Only n00bs would develop a system like that.

Comment: A session cookie is usually just a random ID without relation to the credentials.